# MySQL multiple intersection with self performance

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, inner-join, intersection

For simplicity, let's say we have a table with two columns: uid (user id) and fruit, describing what kinds of fruit a user likes.

E.g.:

```
uid | fruit
----|------------
  1 | Strawberry
  1 | Orange
  2 | Strawberry
  2 | Banana
  3 | Watermelon
```

and so forth.

If I want to find what kinds of fruit are common in N *particular* users (i.e. the intersection N times of the table with itself), the first option is to use an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM Fruits f1
INNER JOIN Fruits f2 USING (fruit)
INNER JOIN Fruits f3 USING (fruit)
...
INNER JOIN Fruits fN USING (fruit)
WHERE f1.uid = 1 AND f2.uid = 2 ... AND fN.uid = M
```

But this kinds of looks silly to me. What if N = 10? or even 20? Is it sensible to do 20 joins? Is there some other join operation I'm missing?

Before learning the "magic" of joins, I used another method, which would apply in my current case as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM Fruits
WHERE uid IN (1, 2, ..., M)
GROUP BY fruit
HAVING COUNT (*) = N
```

It seems much more compact, but I remember somebody telling me to avoid using `GROUP BY` because it is slower than an `INNER JOIN`.

So, I guess my question really is, is there maybe a third method for doing the above? If yes/no, which one is the most efficient?

**-- EDIT --**

So, it seems a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899614/mysql-intersect-results) has been asked before, bearing a resemblance to mine. The two answers provided, are actually the two methods I'm using.

But the question remains. Which one is really more efficient? Is there, maybe, a third one?