# SQL Filter Records On List of Ids

Tags: sql

I have the following junction table:

PersonPhoto

```
+----+----------+---------+
| Id | PersonId | PhotoId | 
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 |       10 |       5 |
|  2 |       11 |       8 |
|  3 |       12 |      28 |
|  4 |       10 |      15 |
|  5 |       10 |      28 |
|  6 |       12 |      15 |
+----+----------+---------+
```

I am trying to filter the table to only return PhotoId based on a list of PersonId's

For example

I would like to get all Photo Ids that have the users 10 and 12 associated with them. Using the table above that should return the following photos ids

15 and 28..

At the moment my efforts are returning 15, 28, 5 - However I don't want 5 to be returned because Person Id 12 is not associated with photo id 5

Here's what I have tried already:

```
select distinct pe.PhotoId 
from PersonPhoto AS pe
where pe.PersonId IN (10, 12)
GROUP BY pe.PhotoId

select pp.PersonId, pp.PhotoId from PersonPhoto AS pp
where pp.PersonId IN (10, 12)
GROUP BY pp.PersonId, pp.PhotoId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pp.PhotoId) = 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: @Somango Please review the thoughtful answers given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get photos that have all desired persons in them, then one method is to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select pp.PhotoId
from PersonPhoto pp
where pp.PersonId in (10, 12)
group by pp.PhotoId
having count(*) = 2;
```

If you can have duplicates in the table, then you should use `count(distinct PersonId)` in the `having` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . As I read the question, this seems to be what the OP wants . . . essentially the photos that have *all* the persons in question in them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry to doubt you, the OP had a wording which wasn't clear IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the `INTERSECT` operator like below. Though it won't work in `MySQL` (You have `SQL Server` tagged)

```
(SELECT DISTINCT PhotoId  FROM PersonPhoto WHERE PersonId = 10)
INTERSECT
(SELECT DISTINCT PhotoId  FROM PersonPhoto WHERE PersonId = 12)
```

For `MySQL` this would work though. Idea taken from [Mysql intersect results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899614/mysql-intersect-results)

```
SELECT DISTINCT PhotoId FROM PersonPhoto
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PhotoId  FROM PersonPhoto WHERE PersonId = 10) a USING (PersonId)
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PhotoId  FROM PersonPhoto WHERE PersonId = 12) b USING (PersonId)
```

Comment: This did work too, but I prefer the accepted answer because there is less duplication. Thanks for the answer though, I appreciate you taking the time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Or write the query using exists. It then reads exactly as you stated it.

```
Select distinct photoId    -- get all Photo Ids that     
From @myT a
Where exists (Select * from @myT  -- have the users 10 
              Where photoId = a.photoId
                 and personId = 10)
  and exists (Select * from @myT  -- and 12 associated with them
              Where photoId = a.photoId
                 and personId = 12)
```

Comment: Yes, I had the fields reversed. try it now.